# How to load a Polymer element after an event occurs?

Tags: polymer

For instance, a user logs in (dynamically, no page refresh) and only then do I want to load up my polymer elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load polymer elements dynamicaly using Polymer.import(['myElement.html']) function. More on: [Polymer helper methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

also you could use the app router element that allows you to use the hash in the URL lo just import the number of elements you are going to use, or even it can load all of them and just charge if the hash is the correct one 
look at https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router

Comment: Interesting, will check that out.